# maven checkstyle unable to find where to insert the includes configuration

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

We have a maven project where I use a checkstyle plugin in the build process and we are very fond of checkstyle. Anyway recently we need to insert web services to our project. The web services classes are not compatible with checkstyle so we want to exclude them when building. So as a way of exclude we want to specify the folders to be included.

I have come across maven.checkstyle.includes and sourceDirectory of checkstyle plugin. But I could not be able to figure out how to use them in pom.xml.

Anyone have an idea?

Here is my checkstyle section of pom.xml

```
<build>
...
<plugin>    
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version>
                    <executions>
                      <execution>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                      </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                        <configLocation>sample_config.xml</configLocation>
                        <sourceDirectory>${maven.checkstyle.includes}</sourceDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
...
</build>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
       <excludes>my/package/**/*</excludes>
```

Add this to your configuration section. These are ant style patterns and you can give the plugin multiple patterns by separating them with a comma.